# Vector serialization in ostream

Tags: c++, serialization

**Problem**
When I load game and hit ship the game shows the ship is missed.This problem doesnt show up in normal game(without load).

I have serializaiotn for loading game board for user and opponent.
I think the error is about loading in serialzation vector but i have no idea how to do this.
vector is portected object in board class.

Implementation of serialzation

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Board &b) {
    for (int row = 0; row < BOARDSIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < BOARDSIZE; col++) {
            out << b.board[row][col]<< ' ';
        }
        out << '\n';
    }
    out << '\n';

    return out;
}

 istream & operator>>(istream & in, Board &b){
    for (int row = 0; row < BOARDSIZE; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < BOARDSIZE; col++) {
            in >> b.board[row][col];
        }
    }
     return in;
}
```

And this is my function for attack made for player:

***getSpaceValue*** return the value of board for example M is miss,X hit etc.

***recordHit*** return boolean,if user hitted the ship it returns true and change board value in this palce to X if not returns false(miss).

```
void Game::atack(Board &b){
    int attemptCounter = 0;
    int xEntry, yEntry;
    bool goodMove=false;
    string entryTemp;

    while(!goodMove){
        if(attemptCounter>0)
            cout << "Wykonales juz ten ruch sprobuj jeszcze raz"<<endl;
        cout <<"Wpisz lokalizacje statku ktory chcesz zatakowac "<<endl;
        entryTemp = validLoc();
        xEntry=static_cast<int>(entryTemp[0]);
        yEntry=static_cast<int>(entryTemp[1]);
        cout<<"Get value wartoswc: "<<(b.getSpaceValue(xEntry-A_ASCII,yEntry-N_ASCII)!=HITTED && b.getSpaceValue(xEntry-A_ASCII, yEntry-N_ASCII)!=MISSED)<<endl;
        if(b.getSpaceValue(xEntry-A_ASCII,yEntry-N_ASCII)!=HITTED && b.getSpaceValue(xEntry-A_ASCII, yEntry-N_ASCII)!=MISSED){
            b.recordHit(xEntry-A_ASCII, yEntry-N_ASCII);
            goodMove = true;
        }
        attemptCounter++;
    }
}
```

And thats the recordHit function on the normal game(whiut loading the board) evrything works fine but when we load its returns always false even if ship is hitted.

```
bool Board::recordHit(int x, int y){
    for(int i=0; i<SHIPS_NUM;i++){
        if(ship[i].recordHit(x,y)){
            board[y][x]=HITTED;

            return true;
        }

    }
    board[y][x]=MISSED;
    return false;
}
```

Edit:

```
Board::Board(){
    for(int i=0; i<BOARDSIZE; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<BOARDSIZE;j++){
            board[i][j]=WATER;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<SHIPS_NUM;i++){
        ship.push_back(Ship5(SHIP_LENGTH[i]));

    }

}
```

Board.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "const.h"
#include "ship.h"

using namespace std;
/**
 * Klasa planszy oraz jej metody
 */
class Board{
protected:
    char board[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];
    vector<Ship5> ship;

public:
    Board();
    Board& operator=(const Board &board1);
    ~Board()= default;
    void printBoard();
    void showUnhiddenBoard();
    bool setShip(int shipID, int x, int y, bool horizontal);
    bool recordHit(int x, int y);
    int HitsNumber();
    int HitsMiss();
    char getSpaceValue(int x,int y);
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out,const Board & b);
    friend istream & operator>>(istream & in, Board &b);
};
```

Posibble values of board

```
const char WATER = '~';
const char SHIP = '-';
const char MISSED = 'M';
const char HITTED = 'X';
const char UNKNOWN = '?';
```

Comment: What is `Board`? What is `Board::board`? Please try to create a [mre] to show us, including how you save and load the board (from where the `<<` and `>>` operators are called).

Comment: If you believe that the serialization / deserialization of your `class Board` is broken, why didn't you expose how `class Board` is declared - incl. the declaration of member variables?

Comment: Seems like a job for a debugger.

Comment: please make your example MINIMAL ... help us help you :))

Comment: The `recordHit(x,y)` combined with `board[y][x]` makes me suspect that you've flipped the "rows" and "columns" at some point.

Comment: What are possible values in table: `b.boarad`?

Comment: @MarekR i edited my question with possible values

Comment: Ok I was afraid it can contain white characters then serialization could fail.

Comment: I see duplicated data which must be consistent to make code work. I see fields: `board` and `ship`. To make a move first `ship` value is used. Problem is deserializtion code doesn't do anything with this `ship` field, so it remains uninitialized and inconsistent with `board`. This must break whole logic. I recommend to remove `ship` since you do not need this extra data.